# How to make chrome use session bus instead of system bus

Tags: linux, docker, google-chrome, dbus

I am trying to make chrome use session dbus on a docker container instead of system bus but failed so far. I have tried the following:

```sh
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1920x1080x24 -pn -noreset >> /tmp/xvfb.log 2>&1 &
export $(dbus-launch)
google-chrome --no-sandbox --no-first-run
```

```sh
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1920x1080x24 -pn -noreset >> /tmp/xvfb.log 2>&1 &
dbus-run-session -- google-chrome --no-sandbox --no-first-run
```

in both cases `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is set but looks like chrome ignores it and tries to connect to `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`:

```
[32:135:0820/204612.634920:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[32:135:0820/204612.635302:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[32:135:0820/204612.635467:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` is hardcoded in chrome's source code, so I needed to do the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=":1"

start_xvfb() {
    [ -e "/tmp/.X1-lock" ] && rm -f /tmp/.X1-lock
    nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 -pn -noreset >> /tmp/xvfb.log 2>&1 &
    echo $!
}

XVFB_PID="$(start_xvfb)"
echo -e "[startup] xvfb started with PID $XVFB_PID"
sleep 1

# make dbus visible to other processes
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus/
export DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE="session"
export DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS="unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_WINDOWID
# open unix socket for dbus, on common setups it's done by systemd
python -c "import socket; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX); s.bind('/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket')"
# start it
dbus-daemon --session --nofork --nosyslog --nopidfile --address=$DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS >> /tmp/dbus.log 2>&1 &
returncode=$?
DBUS_PID=$!
[ $returncode -ne 0 ] && exit $returncode
echo -e "[startup] dbus started with PID $DBUS_PID"
sleep 1

google-chrome --no-sandbox --no-first-run

returncode=$?
kill $XVFB_PID
kill $DBUS_PID
sleep 1
exit $returncode
```

with that chrome logged:

```
[34:144:0820/231701.403705:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(622)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[34:144:0820/231701.404157:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(622)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[34:144:0820/231701.404358:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(622)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
```

but no connection errors happened.